# Betting after all-in/showdown

Tags: all-in, showdown

No limit Texas Holdem, 100/200, 4 players, preflop

player 1 stack - 600,
player 2 stack - 700,
player 3 stack - 5000,
player 4 stack - 3500

First player goes all in for 600 chips

Second player goes all in for 700 chips

Third player calls

Fourth player calls

Should players 1 and 2 show their cards (as there are no actions available for them) or the next betting round will go with all the player cards facing down the table?

Comment: If you need a card that is shown that would effect play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as other active players are in the hand, the cards should be kept face down, so as not to influence the decisions of the other players.